# inRandomOrder() query with ajax return same elements

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query with Laravel

```
$query = Work::inRandomOrder()->where('orientation', $request->get('orientation')->paginate(11);
```

And I have a "load more" button who call 11 others works with each click.

But, I would like display my data in a random order. But with this query, he repeats to me several data. So in my list of works, I have 2 or 3 times the same and obviously, it's not good. Is there a way with RandomOrder () to avoid duplicates?

Thank you

Comment: would a `shuffle()` within each page suffice?

Comment: are you correctly passing the "page" parameter to the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

I believe data is randomized each time the script is loaded, including each time loading dynamicaly 11 more data fields. One way to achieve this it to randomize, store the data in a user's session variable and then get next elements from it. However this might be very heavy.

I would go to a some easily predictable mathemtics, which will look 'random' to the end-user. For example you can get each N-th entry of a query like 1-st, 5-th, 9-th, 13-th ... if N=4 and store just the number N in the user's session.